# Select checkboxes and input box from webpage to download data

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using Excel VBA to navigate to http://airyards.com/tables.html.

- I want to check enable the check boxes for "WR", "TE" and "RB" only.
- Then have the input box (i.e. the "add or remove weeks" box) be a single week, which I can set from a variable earlier in my code. Such as i=5 and input i into that box so I only get data from week 5.
- then lastly, I want to click the "download the data" button and save the data to a specific name and folder; preferably something with my variable "i" in it to identify the week and to a folder of my choice.

I've been using Selenium VBA since I am a little more familiar with it. But I am getting hung up on selecting the check boxes and not able to input my desired week number in the "add or remove weeks" input box.

My code:

```
Dim driver As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Const URL = "http://airyards.com/tables.html"

With driver
    .Start "chrome", "https://www.google.com/"
    .Get URL
    .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='position']/div/div[2]/label/input").Click 'try to click the "TE" check box, but does not work
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to the containing iframe, then check first if selected before making clicks. I am including the way to click the download button, the way to extract the URL for the download. I binary download the file using the extracted URL. I use sendKeys delete to make the week selection.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub MakeSelectionsDownloadFile()
    Dim d As WebDriver, t As Date, downloadURL As String, s As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Const URL = "http://airyards.com/tables.html"
    Const keepWeek As Long = 5

    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .Get URL
        .SwitchToFrame 0

        With .FindElementByCss("[value=WR]")
            If Not .IsSelected Then .Click
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("[value=TE]")
            If Not .IsSelected Then .Click
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("[value=RB]")
            If Not .IsSelected Then .Click
        End With
        With .FindElementByCss("[value=UNK]")
            If .IsSelected Then .Click
        End With

        Dim i As Long, keys As New Selenium.keys
        For i = 1 To 6
            If i <> keepWeek Then
                .FindElementByCss("[data-value='" & i & "']").ClickAndHold
                .SendKeys keys.Delete
            End If
        Next

        t = Timer

        Do
            DoEvents
            downloadURL = .FindElementById("download").Attribute("href")
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While downloadURL = vbNullString
        '  .FindElementById("download").Click

        s = DownloadFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\", downloadURL)
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub

Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal downloadFolder As String, ByVal downloadURL As String) As String
    Dim http As Object, tempArr As Variant
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", downloadURL, False
    http.send

    On Error GoTo errhand

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .write http.responseBody
        .SaveToFile downloadFolder & "Test.csv", 2
        .Close
    End With
    DownloadFile = downloadFolder & "Test.csv"
    Exit Function
errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        MsgBox "Download failed"
    End If
    DownloadFile = vbNullString
End Function
```

Comment: This is great QHarr. How can I input a desired number into the "add or remove weeks" input box? I want to do that before I download the data.

Comment: That I am afraid I am unsure of as yet. What do you do manually? If you have to delete them to remove then it is likely you will have to write javascript and .ExecScript the script. Targeting the element and use .remove() method in JS.